# Suspended for a week after account was compromised

Tags: support, ban

My account on Stack Overflow was compromised yesterday. I share a computer, but I have no idea who did it. I realized, that yesterday, someone has made derogatory comments toward a fellow moderator.

I appologize that this has happened on my account. I have secured my Google Account (I use it to sign in to SO), and I would like to know whom do I contact to resolve this issue.

I noticed that I also got a huge amount of downvotes in less than an hour. I would like to know if a moderator can delete such answers/questions.

Sorry if this is a wrong section to post this in. Please, kindly state in the comments what I need to fix, and I will gladly do so.

Here is the email I got:

> Hello,
>
> I'm writing in reference to your Stack Overflow account:
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/users/2055695/vlad1k
>
> After reports of unusual voting patterns, we've determined that you
>   engaged in a pattern of downvoting against specific users.
>
> The focus of your voting should be on the post, not the user; this
>   kind of community hostile behavior will not be tolerated.
>
> As a result of these actions, I'm placing your account in timed
>   suspension for seven (7) days.
>
> These downvotes have been removed. Please refrain from engaging in
>   malicious or revenge voting in the future.
>
> Regards,
>   -deleted- Stack Overflow moderator
>
> This email was sent from an unmonitored account. Do not reply directly to this email; if you feel this message is incorrect, please respond on Stack Overflow here.

Comment: Your account looks like you voting your self and some found it and reverse it. At least the negatives - are not negative but are from removing positive votes.

Comment: I have received an e-mail saying that someone was was insulting and down voting questions/answers. I am not certain if I can make that message public.

Comment: What do you mean by robo-upvotes?

Comment: @Vlad1k You were serially upvoted over a period of several days. That is, an unlikely pattern of upvotes, most likely by a single user (or at most a couple of users). This upvoting is not accepted and has been reversed.

Comment: I added an e-mail I got. The upvoting is completely different story and it is done by someone I know in real life. Please do not go off topic, this is a question about my **account compromise**. **Edit:** Whoever downvoted - can I know what is wrong with my question so I can improve it?

Comment: For the future, be aware who you are sharing a computer with, although it is rather strange that you do not know this already. Additionally, log out properly and prevent the browser from remembering your login details.

Comment: I have never had any issues like this before. This is the first time I've been compromised.

Comment: Wow... [looks like there've been lots of 'voting irregularities](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2055695/vlad1k?tab=reputation)

Comment: I have not made a self-repping spree, this is (most likely) a real life friend who wanted to help me out. He is new to the site.

Comment: And took the time to create three separate accounts to upvote you?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables I guess that's something for the moderators to deal with. Oscillation happens.

Comment: It's only 1 account, believe me.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Perhaps. I think there's too many comments here that are trying to obliquely suggest that the OP is doing something underhanded. We have no evidence here, so we should give him the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: @Vlad1k Well, no, it's not one account, because in your rep history we can see that several users have been removed. So someone must like you a lot. If you have a hunch who it is (or who they are) tell them to stop, because it won't do you any good in the long run.

Comment: If it would be 3 accounts that would upvote every possible post I make, I would have over 1,000 reputation points. I had only 300 reputation points. If you do the basic math, you would know that you are completely wrong. I am having a bug picking an answer. It's impossible to do, check my other question.

Comment: @Vlad1k It was three different accounts *over time*. Each time, the account was deleted, and they re-created it and started voting again.

Comment: @Vlad1k The maximum rep you can gain in a day from upvotes alone is 200. We can see within your reputation history that at least 3 users have been removed (see the *"User was removed"* events), resulting in a significant rep drop for you. So no, I am more than likely not wrong.

Comment: Okay, I have no idea if you are right or wrong. I have not made such accounts and I do not plan to. I have expected some help from this question, but instead I got blamed and insulted over this, and most likely won't be able to make any more questions. Ridiculous.

Comment: As someone who has had their Google account hacked I sympathize, but a hard message to get across on Meta is for people to think like they're in someone else's shoes.  Kyle gave you the right answer, direct contact is needed at this point.

Comment: Yes, but hey now, I've got insulted and blamed on in the process. No one even explained why I got so many downvotes. (bandwagon)

Comment: @Vlad - Guess the downvotes are from people thinking it is strange for *anyone* to get exactly one upvote for each of his answers every day. And all within a few minutes each time. Other people hitting the rep cap usually get many upvotes for a few answers, and none for the rest.

Comment: Okay, but think about it this way - I use a VPN, make a new account and start upvoting everyone of your answers. That's exactly how I feel. I am not **making** the guy to upvote my questions/posts. He is doing it against my will.

Comment: The issue is that your account was used to serial downvote. Being the victim of the same scheme is irrelevant. The suspension occurred because your account was used to engage in it.

Comment: Since you are responsible for keeping your account secure, you are also responsible for any activity that occurs as a result of someone compromising your account. Make sure your account is secure; full account functionality will resume in six days.

Comment: I don't think this has worked (considering the post and comments today)!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The situation is essentially pretty simple. As explained in the email you received, your account was (somehow) used to target specific users with downvotes. Such targeted downvoting is frowned upon and will cause a suspension. The email does not mention derogatory comments, so I'm not sure if that's part of it, but it might be if you've seen those comments in your history.

This suspension will last for 7 days, during which your reputation is put back to 1. This will be reversed once the suspension ends. It seems however that you have also been serially upvoted, which has been reversed by the system (you do not seem to have gotten a huge amount of downvotes). So not all the rep you gained will come back to you, since at least part of it was undeserved.

If your account has been compromised, all that remains for you is to make sure you secure your account (and probably your Google id) and wait until the timed suspension is over. That is all.

Comment: I looked at the private message the admin sent me, and it had some rude comments coming from my account.

Comment: Then that might be part of the decision. But well, it doesn't really change the situation. You can contact them, as Kyle suggested, but you're most likely going to have to wait this one out.

Answer (score 13):

In cases like this, I believe it is preferred that you contact the dev team directly using the contact us link at the bottom of every page, instead of posting about it on meta.